# Apacheバージョンアップ時のPHPモジュールについて

Tags: php, apache, rhel

■環境
RedHat Enterprise Linux 6.4
php 7.3.4
Apache HTTP Server 2.4.33　→　2.4.41

■質問事項
Apache HTTP Serverのバージョンアップをしようとしています。
Apacheのバージョンアップ後、事前にバックアップを取得しておいたPHPのモジュールを移植しようと考えていますが、
PHPのモジュールも再度コンフィギュレーションする必要はありますでしょうか。

```
cp -p /opt/httpd_bak_`date '+%Y%m%d'`/modules/libphp7.so /opt/httpd/modules/.
```

Answer (score 0):

どちらも恐らくRHELの標準パッケージとは別の手段でインストールされていると思うので、
`httpd.conf` でPHPモジュールをロードするようになっているかを確認する必要があります。

参考:
[PHP: Apache 2.x (Unixシステム用) - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/install.unix.apache2.php)